# Редирект на конце со /

Tags: php, cms, modx

есть два контекста, в web лежит основной каталог, в catalog лежит старые товары(вынес для удобства администрирования)
если в конце адресной строки добавить слеш (site.ru/blog/) то кидает не на странице например site.ru/blog а на старый каталог(то есть страницу другого контекста)
есть такой плагин

```
<?php
if ($modx->event->name == 'OnPageNotFound') { 

    $alias = $modx->context->getOption('request_param_alias', 'q');
    if (!isset($_REQUEST[$alias])) {return false;}
    $request = $_REQUEST[$alias];
    $tmp = explode('/', $request);

    $req = 'product';

    if (($tmp[0] == $req && count($tmp) == 1) || (count($tmp) == 2 && empty($tmp[1])) ) {

        $modx->sendForward('2068');
        return;

    } else if ($tmp[0] == $req && count($tmp) >= 2 && !empty($tmp[1])) {

        $obj = $modx->getObject('modResource', array('uri' => $request));
        $modx->sendForward($obj->get('id'));
        return;

    } else if ($tmp[0] != $req && $tmp[0] != 'assets') {

        $modx->switchContext('web');
        return;
    }

}
```

настройки контекста
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если отключить плагин, что будет?
В настройках htaccess/ ngigx (или иного веб-сервера) ничего хитрого?
В настройках контекстов все проверили?
Какое значение системной переменной container_suffix?
А еще уточните пожалуйста версию MODX.

Comment: container_suffix = ' ', версия 2.7.1, скрин настроек скинул в вопрос, если плагин отключить то все работает, но при переходе на каталог в другом контексте выдает 404